# How to send Server request only once after 7 days?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which scenario is something like that when user keep the app in their device, Then after 7 days I have to send server request to notify server about that.How can I do that .

Note:- I have only have to send server request after 7 days only once not again after seven days.

Comment: from server side use cronejob

Comment: Wait for a few mins, I am sending you the whole code

Answer (score 3):

As i told you. Here is the code. I have mentioned the place where you need to implement the Server request. You don't need to change anything else in it. Have Fun.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences sharePref;
String endTime, currentTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.child);
    sharePref=getSharedPreferences("App", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(sharePref.getBoolean("isFirstTime", true)) {
        checkFinalTime();
    }
    else if (!sharePref.getBoolean("isRequestSend", false)){
        checkRemainingTime();
    }
}

private void checkFinalTime(){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);

    endTime = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" +
            String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + " " + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" +
            String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    Log.d("End Time", endTime);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharePref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", false);
    editor.putString("endTime", endTime);
    editor.apply();
}

private void checkRemainingTime() {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" +
            String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + " " + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" +
            String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    endTime = sharePref.getString("endTime", null);

    Log.d("Current Time", currentTime);
    Log.d("End Time", endTime);

    if (endTime != null) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try {
            d1 = format.parse(currentTime);
            d2 = format.parse(endTime);

            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            if (diff >= 0) {

                // Do the Server Request here. Don't delete anything.

                Log.d("Diff", String.valueOf(diff));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharePref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("isRequestSend", true);
                editor.apply();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Take Care

Comment: what about if app is not open

Comment: and also not in background

Comment: No, Not this, when you open the app first time, it will calculate the next 7 days and then whenever you open the app it will compare the endDate with the current date and if 7 days are completed it will send the request to the server.

Comment: it will calculate only first app launch aur every app launch

Comment: it will send server request whether app is not in background?

Comment: On the first launch, it will calculate the date after a week and save it permanently.

Comment: After the first launch, whenever the app launches, it'll get the current date and compare it with the permanent saved date until the save date is not matched with the current date

Comment: when the date matches, it'll send the request to the server and after that, this code will never execute. as you wanted as well.

Comment: but what about if user not launch app till 7 days

Answer (score 0):

Try to schedule the "sending request to server task" with Timer, something like that, change to your relevant arguments.

```
 TimerTask tasknew = new TimerSchedulePeriod();
 Timer timer = new Timer();

 // scheduling the task at interval
 timer.schedule(tasknew,100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

You can get the app install time from

`PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("app.package.name", 0);
String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;
long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified();`

You can get the current date of the system, and easily check if 7 days are over, you can have the flag to check if  api hit or not.

You can use service or do it when user start the activity.